# Cannot set Monitor resolution

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, monitor

I installed Ubuntu 16.04. And I have an external monitor (24 inch) to my laptop. The 1920x1200 resolution is not optional at Display settings. So I tried this code below:

```
cvt 1920 1200 60
xrandr --newmode "1920x1200_60.00"  193.25  1920 2056 2256 2592  1200 1203 1209 1245 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 "1920x1200_60.00"
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode "1920x1200_60.00"
```

I got this error message:

```
xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed
```

Any idea?

Comment: Are you actually using VGA? Does the monitor and your laptop also have HDMI, Display Port or DVI? If so, try it with those. Even though VGA can work with HD, it's known to cause problems sometimes.